# Counting and finding sum of combination of Dimensional attributes

Tags: tableau-api

Got a field in Excel:

```
Treament Status

 IT
 IT
 SD
 USD
 SD
 SD
 USD
```

I need to use a calculated field to find a Percentage of total using this mathematical formula, based on the number of times certain dimensional attributes appears in the column i.e. Count:

% of R = [Count(SD)+Count(IT)]/[Count(Total of everything in Treatment Status)]

I know how to use the COUNT and SUM functions but I'm trying to connect the dots here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple approach without writing any calculations is

1. Put Treatment Status on the Row shelf (double click should do it)
2. Number of Records on the Text Shelf (double click on it for a shortcut)
3. Then right click on the Number of Records field on the marks card and select Quick Table Calc -> Percent of Total

If you want to combine the SD and IT rows, select both SD and IT, then use the paperclip icon to group them together

The effect is to generate a query like select count(1) from xxx group by TreatmentStatus, and then to compute the percentages in Tableau acting upon the query results.

Answer (score 0):

You need the TOTAL function. This should do it.

```
% of R = [Count(SD)+Count(IT)]/TOTAL(COUNT([Treatment Status]))
```

Comment: What does Count(SD) mean in SQL If Treatment Status is a field (column) and "SD" is one of the possible values. Count([Treatment Status]) is well defined, ie. the number of rows that have a non-null value in that column. But SD is not a column.

Comment: @AlexBlakemore I'm not sure if your question was me or OP. But OP mentioned that he knew how to use COUNT and SUM. So I just borrowed from his formula. Count(SD) in my view was a calc field already `if [treatment status] = 'SD' then 1 end`

Comment: That makes sense, presuming you wrap a Count() around the if of course. Just the answer as it written doesn't work unless someone fills in those details